# Transiciones de elementos entre actividades

Tags: java, android, android-layout

¿Hay alguna manera de hacer transiciones entre actividades que no sea de la siguiente manera?

```
ActivityOptions transitionActivityOptions;
transitionActivityOptions = makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity, sharedView, "shared_image");
v.getContext().startActivity(i, transitionActivityOptions.toBundle());
```

Es que este método esta implementado a partir de la API 21 y me gustaría poder hacer esos efectos en versiones anteriores de Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

me imagino que hay varias maneras de hacerlo, claro que imposible que sea tan facil como utilizar la ventaja de la API 21 en adelante, sin embargo y haciendo mención a esta misma pregunta en StackOverFlow en ingles

[Activity transition on lower api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27344357/android-5-activity-transition-on-lower-api)

> We added a lot of stuff in Lollipop to make Activity Transitions work well. It is possible to do Activity Transitions manually (in earlier versions), but you will encounter problems in some cases and the return transition is likely going to work only in the simplest case. Chet Haase has a devbyte on this here.
>
> Animations between fragments were possible earlier, though the API
>   isn't as easy to use as in Lollipop's Fragment Transitions.
>
> We thought a lot about back porting transitions to earlier versions in
>   the support library. It may still happen. If so, we should also be
>   able to do something for Fragment Transitions.

(Lo intente traducir)

> Es posible hacer transiciones entre Activitys manualmente (versiones anteriores) pero para que no se produzcan mayores problemas en la transicion el retorno va a trabajar probablemente solo en casos sencillos. [Un ejemplo aqui](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPxkoe2MraA). Fue posible utilizar animaciones en versiones anteriores pero nunca tan facil como de `Lollipop` en adelante.